# facebook tab page app cannot retrieve user session on IE and mobile browser

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, session

I have a problem with my facebook tab page application written with PHP when it runs on IE and on mobile browser.

I am using sessions, and i do a check to see if user session has been set or access has been allowed, if not, it redirects to the main page (index.php).

When on IE, for a new user, the iframe displays a facebook logo which on click, asks the user for access permission. After allowing access, i get redirected back to the main page for awhile before i get hit with an "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error.

When on mobile browser (e.g. iPhone Safari, Android web browser), i just get redirected back to the main page.

I believe this is a session problem because I echo a $facebook->getUser() and it always returns a 0.

The annoying thing is that, this works on certain computers running IE8 and IE9 but not on some others. I have been debugging for the last 2 days or so and have tried putting

```
<?php header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

at the top. The Privacy settings of IE is set to Medium, and this problem is resolved when I set my browser Privacy settings to Accept All Cookies.

Is there anyway I can have the application run properly when on Medium security settings on IE? and also, is this the same problem as to why i am getting issues on my mobile browser?

Thanks in advance everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on Session data as you can never get it right on all browsers. I faced similar issues when I started.

I encrypt all information and send it as a query string parameter.

This will work on all browsers with no issues :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam. But right now, I am facing the problem that the app request approval is not stored for first time users. So after they click Allow access and get redirected to the main page, the page fails with a content cannot be loaded in frame. Did you face such problems as well?

Comment: You just append the encrypted signedrequest to the redirect_uri component. Or you can redirect it to a page that then uses Javascript to get the parent window. I think window.top or location.top (can't quite remember) and then set it back to your Facebook page and the app specifically, which is something similar to https://www.facebook.com/pagename?sk_app=xxxxxxxx. Then it will reload your app with the signed request again and the user will have approved your app :)

Comment: hello adam, have been trying to read up on what exactly to do with the signed_request but cant exactly find what i am looking for because i am still very new to FB App development. any chance you could point me towards the right direction? getting rather desperate now after spending so much time on this. :(

Comment: Sample code in PHP here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/